# How to avoid instagram error 429 The maximum number of requests per hour has been exceeded

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, http-status-code-429

I do an application which deletes comments on Instagram since Saturday 31st of October, I get this response when I use API  to delete comments:

```
{"error_type":"OAuthRateLimitException","code":429,"error_message":"The maximum number of requests per hour has been exceeded...."}}.
```

I see that they did a modification one year ago for the limits of the number of requests, but I don't have this error during this execution since before the update.
How to avoid it? 
Is it necessary to retrieve a new token or is there an another way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a secure API request to get a higher limit. I think you missed this email from Instagram:

> When we announced our publishing guidelines for likes/relationship
> actions, we also introduced a new technique to sign API requests. As
> part of this announcement we set a deprecation date for the previous
> signed-headers functionality to Sept 1, 2015.
>
> This email is to let you know that support for signed-headers has now
> been deprecated. We know that a number of developers (including your
> company) are still relying on this option, and have whitelisted your
> client_id for an extended period. Please plan the migration to
> securing your application with signed-requests as soon as possible.
> You can learn more about this feature here:
> https://instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/.
>
> The extended support will end on Nov 1 2015. You will see your
> rate-limits for publishing likes/follows/comments reduced if you
> haven’t migrated after this date.